# how to deploy a react app bundled with webpack on EC2

Tags: reactjs, amazon-ec2, webpack

I have built an Application using react and I want to deploy it on my EC2 instance. I have bundled it using `webpack` and I was using `webpack-dev-server` for development purposes. The bundler has produced an output with public directory and index.js as the output of my code. I have included this index.js in my index.html and now I want to deploy it on my EC2 instance. Is there any specific http server which I can use to deploy this app. I am new to web application development so any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `apache` or `ngnix` and deploy it easily.

Comment: can you send me a link or reference where I can read more about it please